# How to know what arguments to pass to a script

Tags: language-agnostic

Putting aside the security implications of running a script someone gives me, how can I tell, in advance, that the script requires a certain number of arguments? Without reading the code.

If someone just gives me a script, is there a way to know that it takes 4 arguments or whatever the case may be?

I guess I am looking for a best practices answer. I am obviously not a developer and just curious as to how some things are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of script you want to know ? Shell or Windows Batch or Ruby or Python ?

For scripts in Python, It's impossible to know the number of arguments without reading the code. In Python, we can pass any arguments into Python script. The script determines whether to use them.

Comment: That answers my question. I didn't have a specific language in mind. Programming in general is alien to me and there are fundamental things I do not know. Just trying to sort it all out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected etiquette that the script's author(s) provide documentation describing some or all of: the script's purpose, expected arguments and operational modes.

Some scripts generate an abbreviated usage message (listing accepted arguments) when run with an appropriate help switch, eg `theScript -h`, `theScript --help` or `theScript /?`.

Scripts that form part of an installable tool, package or application may have an associated "manpage" (`man theScript`) or published documentation, eg hypertext pages, text files, printed manuals or pages on the Internet. Such documentation might be found by browsing the filesystem / Start menu (Windows) / provided materials and original installation media or by searching the Web.

Of course, this applies only by convention; generally there is no contract that is enforced on the script by a computer system. If someone is "giving you a script" (of questionable origin) then none of the above is guaranteed.

If you expressly receive a script (containing text readable in an editor and not binary gibberish) then the contents might include a section of prose containing useful information without your resorting to reading and understanding the "code".

Comment: Thank you, kindly. That is most helpful, in addition to it making sense.